# How to prove a series converge when I have only some bound for $|a_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Recently I've been blocked on a problem as follow :

Let $a_n\in \mathbb{R} $ and $ a ≤ |a_n| ≤ b$ In this case $a \ne b$ so obviously $a<b$

(In the specific question both $a<b<1$ and I guess that if they are over $1$ the series diverges)

I don't know what I should do to prove it, I guess it has something to do with $-b\le a_n \le b $ or $0\le |a_n|\le b$ but I can't think of anything. The correct answer is that  $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^n|$ converges. What's worse is that I should be able to find a value as $|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^n|≤c$ with $c$ a reel number...

Edit: Here's the full statement: $1/4≤|a_n|≤1/2$ for every n ≥ 0 and the answer requested is : $∑a_n^n$ converge and $|∑a_n^n|≤2$
Thank you in advance.

Comment: welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Your statement is incorrect. For example: $$0\leq \left|\frac{1}{n}\right|\leq \frac{3}{4}\,\,\, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$ But:$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ does not converge.

Comment: What exactly is the statement of the problem?

Comment: The statement is : $1/4 ≤ |a_n|≤ 1/2$ for every n ≥ 0 and the answer requested is : $\sum a_n^n$ converge and $ |\sum a_n^n| ≤ 2$ 

Yeah there is a problem in my question I forgot the power of n sorry

Comment: @user15757055: this isn't included in your prompt. Rewiev it. Thanks.

Comment: your statement isn't a question What is the question? Please update you answer with additional information even if you have posted them as comments.

Comment: I just did but it's more that I'm looking for a way to resolve rather than this result specifically

Comment: **Hint:** Compare your series to a geometric series.

Comment: $|\sum a_n^n| \leq \sum |a_n^n| \leq \sum 2^{-n}$
Hopefully you know the sum of the series on the far right...

Comment: Oh I get it thanks, I guess since I have to prove $|\sum a_n^n|≤2$ I need to find another series to compare but at least I understand why it's less than 1 now.

Comment: Right ahahah for some reason I thought the reverse, thanks everyone